# Jenkins plugin for collecting user input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a Jenkins Pipeline job.

I want to achieve this: in the job home page, I want an HTML input tag, before each time manually triggering the build, I first fill in something in the tag, then the value can be retrieved and used in the pipeline script during the build.

It there a plugin for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `Build with parameter` plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a so-called [*Parameterized Build*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

In your pipeline definition, you can add these build parameters using the [`properties`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#properties-set-job-properties) step, which comes with the *workflow-multibranch* plugin.

A simple example would be as follows:

```java
properties([
  parameters([
    string(name: 'DEPLOY_ENV', defaultValue: 'TESTING', description: 'The target environment', )
   ])
])
```

P.S: As this feature is quite hidden, I wrote a [blog post](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines) about this a few weeks ago.

Comment: wow~ Thanks, Stephen, this is exactly what I want. @StephenKing